# Java regular expression matching no carriage return followed by a linefeed

Tags: java, regex

I've tried `(^\r)\n` but this doesn't work.

How do you do this?

(I appreciate that in Java-like code you need to use `(^\\r)\\n`)

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements:

- `[^\r]\n`  - linefeed that is preceded with any character but a carriage return. This means *there must be a character before the linefeed* and *two symbols will be matched*.
- `(?<!\r)\n` - linefeed that is not preceded with a carriage return. This means there *only newline symbol will get matched* and `\r` will only be tested for presence (as `(?<!\r)` is a negative lookbehind, a *zero-width assertion* that does not consume any text, but returns true if the pattern inside it is absent right before the current position in the string).

For a demo, please check these two links:

- At [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), [`(?<!\r)\n` is matching](https://regex101.com/r/gO2qV9/1) as linebreaks are pure `\n` at the Web site
- At [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester), [the same pattern does not match anything](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5cr)%5cn&i=Line+1%0d%0aLine+2) as linebreaks are `\r\n` there.